# 'RatingModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class

Tags: angular

i'm trying to use the starrating module in angular 13. Installed the package but always getting the following error whenever I call the module in AppModule:

```
'RatingModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.
rating.module.d.ts(1, 22): This likely means that the library (ng-starrating) which declares 
RatingModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. 
Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking 
with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.
```

I have tried a couple of solutions found on the internet but none of them worked for me, has anyone been through this error? I appreciate your help!

Comment: try running `npx ngcc` or `node ./node_modules/.bin/ngcc`

Comment: none of them worked, any alternative?

Comment: Last update for `ng-starrating` was 3 years ago.. are you sure it's still compatible with Angular v13?

Comment: Indeed, I found a way by modifying the tsconfig.app.json file and re-building the project but i'm not sure whether it's the convenient solution or not!

Answer (score 2):

I tried running the `npx ngcc`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar before and i solved with try clearing the cache and removing and reinstalling node_modules

Best regards!

Comment: Thank you for that! I tried it but didn't work in my case!