# Error while import RatingModule angular 17

Tags: angular

I tried to import RatingModule but showing me an error. How can I fix it ?

code:

```
import { RatingModule } from 'ng-starrating';
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    RatingModule
  ],
```

Error:

```
 TS-996002: 'RatingModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.module.ts:20:4:
      20 │     RatingModule
         ╵     ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  This likely means that the library (ng-starrating) which declares RatingModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

    node_modules/ng-starrating/lib/rating.module.d.ts:1:21:
      1 │ export declare class RatingModule {
```

Comment: I also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73949788/ratingmodule-does-not-appear-to-be-an-ngmodule-class
But there no solution

Answer (score 0):

Please find below a working stackblitz highlighting it working.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RatingModule } from 'ng-starrating';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RatingModule],
  template: `
    <div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    ng-starrating demo
  </h1>
  <star-rating [value]="5" [totalstars]="5" checkedcolor="red" uncheckedcolor="black" size="24px"></star-rating>
</div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[satckblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ky9fws)

If it still does not work please share it back with the issue replicated!